# Command-line HTML formatter that doesn't modify HTML in any way, just indents?

Tags: html, linux, shell, ubuntu, formatting

I've been trying to tidy (read: HTML Tidy) up my HTML, but it keeps trying to "fix" my HTML which actually breaks the output. I don't have time to fix all this "invalid" HTML... it renders fine in every browser, I just want to format it so that I can actually read it. Is there such a tool?

Comment: Out of pure voyeuristic curiosity, can you link to the HTML?

Comment: The fact that your "invalid" HTML renders fine in every browser may just be a testament to the forgiving nature of browsers.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Nope. Company property. @pavium: It may be. That, and I'm sure the code is slathered with browser-specific fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening it in vim (a file editor) then use this:

```
gg=G
```

That will reindent (`=`) every line from the first line (`gg`) to the last (`G`).  It will only work if the new lines already exist.  If you need to insert new lines you could add a regex to look for close tags and then insert a new line.

```
%s/\>/\>\\n/g
```

`%s` whole file regex match closing tag > and replace with > new line.

If you're new to vim you can use `:wq` to write (`w`)[save] and quit `q`

Comment: i asked for command-line because i want to hook my IDE (komodo edit) into it. switching back and forth between editors would defeat the purpose. also, yes, new-lines need to be added....and i'm not about to write a regex to do so.